# Set LONG data type using a Prepared Statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, database-partitioning

My situation is that I need to create DB partitions on the fly at certain times. I'm using a `Statement` like the following:

```
alter table table_name split partition default_partition values (' +
id + ') into (  partition " + partitionName + ", partition
default_partition) update indexes
```

This works fine and does exactly what I expect. However, the value of `id` comes from input that an unauthorized person could potentially access. So, the above statement is **vulnerable to an SQL injection attack**. I would like to use a `PreparedStatement`, but I cannot figure out how.

The problem is that the partition table in oracle puts the "`id`" value into the HIGH_VALUE column which is a LONG. I see no appropriate setter to do this (since String can't work). I've tried using the various stream messages, with both a `StringReader` and `ByteArrayInputStream` as the value to no avail. I know LONGs aren't supposed to be used anymore but that's the way Oracle has it so I can't really get around it.

When I try with any of those ways, this is what I get:

```
ORA-14308: partition bound element must be one of: string, datetime or interval literal, number, or NULL
```

The Oracle doc has good info on how to get a LONG (the oracle data type, which is like a LOB) but not how to set it. Could anyone help me with this? I've also looked into the Oracle implementation of the JDBC driver but it too doesn't seem to have a setLONG type method. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I thought that PreparedStatement had a method on it called 'setLong(int, long)':
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Will that not work?

Comment: Yes, LONG oracle type is basically a LOB. So, it's not a long like a Java long.

Comment: Since Oracle's LONG is character data (fools), have you tried `setString(int, id.toString())`?  What set methods have you tried?

Comment: I have tried all of them that make sense (ie, not decimal, float, etc). So, all the stream ones, String, etc. I've also tried CLOB/LOB/etc, char, etc. Using the Oracle specific impl, I tried setRAW setOracleAsObject and a few others with no success. It just seems so crazy to me that Oracle recommends against using LONG and then goes ahead and continues to use it while making it difficult to work with, heh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use bind variables with DDL.  You're not going to be able to use a `PreparedStatement` and call any `setXXXX` methods in your DDL statement.

Splitting partitions on the fly based on user input is, at the very least, a very unusual design.  I would tend to suspect that you'd be better served with something like [interval partitioning](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/PartitioningEnhancements_11gR1.php#interval_partitioning) where Oracle takes care of creating new partitions when they are needed or hash partitioning rather than range partitioning.  Assuming it truly makes sense to manually create new partitions on the fly, however, you'll have to write code to validate that the 'id' and 'partitionName' values are valid in order to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Well, I was just trying to simplify things. It's not like any user can do this. It will be quite restricted but we would still like to make sure we're protected in case either those few users turn rotten or someone gains access in another way. I will use the validation route, even though it's not quite the guarantee the PS would have been. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is id a String, if so, why don't you validate it before?

```
    try {
        id = Long.valueOf(unsafeId);
        //do more validations here
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not a valid input.");
    }
```

Comment: It's not actually a Long. The type is LONG in the db, which is actually just char data. Additionally, the form a valid id can take is varied (and id is a bad name, I replaced the actual name with that just for the example).